# Diagnose issues in third party assembly, C# .NET

Tags: c#

I want to find out how to diagnose issues in a third party assembly. I don't have source code of it. Are there tools or methodologies?

Thanks

Comment: You should be able to use Reflection for this.

Comment: Depends on the issue you are having.  Cannot load the assembly,  exceptions while calling methods, etc?  There are different tools to diagnose problems (i.e. Fusion Log Viewer, Reflector, ILDasm...), however without knowing the details of the problem, it is hard to offer a specific solution.

Comment: Some free alternatives to Reflector: JetBrains DotPeek, Telerik JustDecompile and IlSpy

Comment: @Ilya Kogan How does Resharper help me diagnose the issue?

Comment: @ Brian Driscoll, could elaborate on using Reflection? Do you mean writing code?

Comment: @w0lf thanks, I will check them out.

Comment: @Anurag Ranjhan thanks, I will check out the recommended tools.

Comment: When you have Resharper, you can just right-click a method and select "Go to implementation", and then you see a disassembly of the external assembly into C#.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Reflector in it's pro version provides debugging into third party assemblies: http://www.reflector.net/vspro/

(Though I've never tested it)

Comment: So reflector can decompile only assemblies that are not protected.

Answer (score 2):

I will usually use Reflector to disassemble the code and see what it might be doing.

Answer (score 2):

You can go really oldschool and just decompile it with [ILDasm.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7dy01k1%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)  Of course that requires quite a bit of effort, and you have to be able to read IL.

And of course [.NET Reflector](http://www.reflector.net/) is the standard goto, although you have to pay for it now, because RegGate broke their promise to keep it free.

Speaking of free, and just as good as Reflector [ILSpy](http://wiki.sharpdevelop.net/ILSpy.ashx) is an option too.

Comment: So reflector can decompile only assemblies that are not protected.

Answer (score 0):

You can use JetBrian's dotPeek. It free and supports .NET 1.0-4.0 assemblies. Look [here](http://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/)